# Persistant data for Debezium Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, debezium

I am trying to implement a CDC architecture using Debezium ,Kafka and Kafka-Connect using Docker Compose . The issue I am facing is I want to keep persistant data i.e even after the docker container is stopped or restarted the connector offsets and data should remain persistant , currently it reset the data of debezium connector

```
`version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: debezium/example-mysql:1.8
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: debezium
      MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpw

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.3
    container_name: zookeerper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.5.3
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE : 200000000
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES : 200000000
      KAFKA_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES : 200000000
      KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE : 200000000
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES : 200000000
      KAFKA_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES : 200000000
      KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 5048576
      KAFKA_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 5048576
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES: 5048576
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_POLL_RECORDS : 300
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'

  schema-registry:
    container_name: schema-registry
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:4.0.3
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'

  kafka-connect:
      container_name: kafka-connect
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest
      ports:
        - '8083:8083'
      links:
        - kafka
        - zookeeper
      environment:
         - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
         - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=medium_debezium
         - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
         - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
         - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
         - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
         - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
         - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
         - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=medium_debezium
         - KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE=200000000
         - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=200000000
         - KAFKA_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES=200000000
         - CONNECT_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE=5048576
         - CONNECT_CONSUMER_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES=5048576
         - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083 
         - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
         - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
         - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
         - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
         - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/connectors,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/
      command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Installing Connector"
          confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:2.2.1
          confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:10.5.1
          #
          echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
          /etc/confluent/docker/run &
          #
          sleep infinity
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'
  aws-s3:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: aws-s3
    environment:
      SERVICES : s3:5000
      HOSTNAME : aws-s3
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID : "KEY"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY :  "KEY"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  connector-sender:
    container_name: connector-sender
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.3
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/conf
    depends_on:
      - kafka-connect
    command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Wainting for kafka connect to start..."
          until [[ "$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} kafka-connect:8083/connectors)" -eq 200 ]]; do
            sleep 1
          done
          echo -e "Sending connector"
          curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" kafka-connect:8083/connectors/ -d @/conf/mysql_config.json
`
```

attaching the Docker commpose image

Answer (score 0):

Debezium stores data in Kafka. You need to mount a volume for the Kafka (and Zookeeper) container.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/external-volumes.html